# How much disk space is needed for a social network?

Tags: self-hosted

I'm going to run a social network website that will have upto 1000 users. how much disk space is needed for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That can't be told because you can't know how active the site will be. If you have upload option you might need a lot. You can calculate the required space like :

Each member uploads a HD profile picture : Apox 3 MB X 1000 = 3 GB

If they upload a video : Let's say 200 MB x 1000 =  20 GB .

If you ask me I would buy a VPS which can be upgraded easily if needed. Start on a low plan ( 20 GB ) and go up if needed just for a few bucks.